# What is the equivalent of AfterSaveCallback in Spring Boot framework for JPA based lifecycle events

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-elasticsearch

What is the equivalent of `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.event.AfterSaveCallback` in Spring Boot JPA framework. We would like to add a transient variable on AfterSaveCallback but we are having an issue trying to inject `@Value` in `javax.persistence.PostLoad`

Comment: There is no Spring Boot JPA framework there is just JPA. You can write a global or entity listener for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`@PostUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/persistence/javadoc-1_0-fr/javax/persistence/PostUpdate.html).[Here is an example how to use the various lifecycle methods of JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events)